# How to get a timestamp of 6 months back using Java Instant?

Tags: java

If today is 6/24/2020, I want a UTC timestamp of 1/24/2020 12:00am regardless of the time difference. I don't want to take into account hrs, min, sec etc.

Here is what I'm doing right now:

```
    private Timestamp setTimeBack(int months)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -months);

        return new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
    }
```

Wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this

Comment: Why are you using the `Timestamp` class, which is intended for JDBC and should probably be avoided if your JDBC supports modern time objects?

Answer (score 3):

If  you're on java 8:

```java
LocalDateTime sixMonthsAgo = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(6).atTime(0, 0);
return Timestamp.valueOf(sixMonthsAgo);
```

Comment: I noticed your code snippet has a parameter of `months`, but your question title specifically mentioned six months so I've hard coded that in. If the parameter is needed you could do: `LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(months);`

Comment: Calling `withHour(0)` and `withMinute(0)` has no effect, as both methods return *a new instance*. You need to store the return value into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clean one-liner for Java 8:

```
Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(6).atStartOfDay());
```

Note that if the resulting day doesn't exist then this will round down to the nearest real day

You can test its results with this simple program:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate[] testDates = {
                LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 24), // results in `2019-12-24 00:00:00.0`
                LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 31), // results in `2020-02-29 00:00:00.0` rounding down to a real day
        };
        for (LocalDate date : testDates) {
            System.out.println(date + " => " + minusMonthsToTimestamp(date, 6));
        }
    }

    public static Timestamp minusMonthsToTimestamp(LocalDate date, int minusMonths) {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(date.minusMonths(minusMonths).atStartOfDay());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
private Timestamp setTimeBack(int months)
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  //Get current date/month i.e 24 June, 2020
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));//To make UTC
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -months);   //Go to date, 6 months ago 24 December, 2019
        return new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
    }
```

Comment: I would not recommend using `Calendar`, `Date` or `DateFormat` in any new code. These classes are obsolete, have concurrency issues, and are written inefficiently. New code should use `java.time` packages.